# How to append multiple audio files to a currently playing audio using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have a program that plays songs from the server. To make it more efficient i split the audio file on server into segments and the send them to the client using Ajax as base64 encoded. The HTML5 native audio player plays the base64 audio segment but when playing the next audio segment, it pauses a little and then plays. The retrieved segments are stored in IndexedDB for quick access but still it causes a pause in the playback. How to make the program more efficient as well as fix the audio pause happening between switching segments.

Is there any other way of appending audio file to a currently playing audio source without any pause using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The [Media Source Extensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API) can do that, but note that you are just reinventing [Range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests) and caching, which are exactly what browsers already do for fetching media, but they do it better since they don't add the overhead of base64 on it.

So the "other way" is to configure your server to accept Range requests, to serve your file the most basically as possible in a single file, and to let the browser do its job.

Comment: Can you show how to use "accept Range requests" to serve files?

Comment: what backend architecure are you using?

Comment: I'm just using an Apache server running PHP 7.4.2. The segment of a file x.mp3 are stored on the server namely as x_1.mp3,x_2.mp3,x_3.mp3.... The Ajax fetches those segments and pushes to the indexedDb for future plays.

Comment: The point of my answer is that you don't need nor should chunk your file. Serve a single full file. The browser and the server will both take care of sending only what they need, by doing Range Requests. Unless you did explicitly disable it, your apache server should be able to handle Range requests out of the box. You can try the curl request provided in the MDN article I did point to.